# How to make a timer in js

Tags: javascript, timer

So I left my old projects and decided to make a website like trello.com it's just a task list site and I wanted to make the task disappear after sometime but I don't know how to create a time I tried to make a`string` nothing I tried everything I know help
Here's the js

```
//Don't care about the comment code
/*let todos = document.querySelector('ul')
let form = document.querySelector('form')
let idk = document.querySelector("[name='todo']")
let todo = []
*/
let timer = 80
/*function addtodos(todostext) {
  todo.push(todostext)
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  const button = document.createElement('button')
  li.innerHTML = todostext
  button.innerHTML = "done"
  todos.appendChild(li)
  li.appendChild(button)
}
form.onsubmit =(event) =>{
  event.preventDefault();
  addtodos(idk.value)
}*/
function minustimer() {
  --timer;
  
}

document.write(timer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside an anonymous function of `setInterval`, you can remove the task item (instead of my console.log). The item will be removed after a specific amount of time given as a callback of `setInterval`. Basically, `setInterval` waits some time to execute a code block. More information in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

```
function minustimer(){
    setInterval(()=>{
        console.log("Remove the item after 5000 milliseconds")
    },5000)
}

minustimer()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clearInTimeout(timeSecond) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // use you code clear
        document.write("clear")
        // 
    }, timeSecond * 1000)
}
clearInTimeout(5);
```

the "clear" will be print after 5 seconds

Comment: Well this can be useful thanks  but I want the user to see a count down so that he knows when everything is cleared